# Creating Four Separate Pivot Tables from Four Excel Sheets in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error, pivot-table

I have four Excel worksheets exported from Access. I created a full query (pivot cache and pivot table) for one of those worksheets. I need to create 3 more separate pivot tables, all to go within this same workbook.

I tried breaking it out into sub functions, so I saved the Excel workbook and closed it, ended the sub function, and then began another by opening the Excel workbook and using much of the same query to establish a new pivot cache.

When making my new pivot cache I got the error

> 1004 Application or Undefined Error

See code below. (It works when used in the previous sub function that creates the first pivot table.)

```
Set xlPC = xlbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "Superdash_tbl", xlPivotTableVersion15)
xlSheet.Select
xlbook.TableStyles("PivotStyleMedium2").Duplicate ("CM Style - Dk Blue")
'''''The above line is what is causing the error''''''
```

I wouldn't think that a For Loop would work, because each Pivot Table is structured and labeled differently.

How do I include each of these four pivot tables?

Answer (score 1):

> This answer may be more *directly* on-topic since [I think] I understand your issue - however my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51347671/8112776) stands as my opinion of an easier way to automate a report including one or more Pivot Tables..

**Short answer**: creating a second pivot table is exactly like creating the original pivot table.

It looks like you were trying to find a method to duplicate an existing Pivot Table, which resulted in you using [**the `TableStyle.Duplicate` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/tablestyle-duplicate-method-excel) (in your example).  However, as the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/tablestyle-duplicate-method-excel) says, it:

> *Duplicates the TableStyle object and returns a reference to the new copy.*

...this method is has nothing to do with Pivot Tables. (Remember, Pivot Tables and Tables are not the same thing.)

---

Whatever steps you took to create the first Pivot Table, run them again with a new destination, and you will have another Pivot Table.

I don't know of any methods I would recommend for duplicating-then-changing a pivot table, although I wouldn't recommend building pivot tables programmatically anyhow... hence my suggestion about building a template for automation instead.

Refer to the links including documentation for the [Pivot Table object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivottable-object-excel), including all applicable methods you can use with pivot tables.  If you're going to have a ton of Pivot Tables looking at the same data, you can consider re-using the Pivot Cache, but all-around programmatic Pivot Tables are quite advanced and therefore prone to coding complexities.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**PivotTable Object** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivottable-object-excel)
- MSDN : [**PivotCache.CreatePivotTable Method** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivotcache-createpivottable-method-excel)
- MSDN : [**PivotCache Object** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivotcache-object-excel)

Comment: If based on same source then simply copy the existing sheet with pivottable then programmtically change the required parameters. If based on different sources, yes as @ashleedawg outlines, and change the source and pivottable name.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that, instead of trying to do all this complicated  design and formatting programmatically every time the data updates, turn it around, and create a beautiful, customized template **manually** - using the current dataset, and thereby ***create a template*** so all formatting is ready to **auto-update** simply by overwriting a hidden "Data tab" (with VBA or scheduled) with updated data at any time.

I know this isn't the solution you were looking for but I'm recommending it anyway. You would not believe how many reports and "dashboards" I've automated in this manner in the past.

### Creating a template for a "set-it-and-forget-it" automated Access⇒Excel report

1. Setup one or more queries that return *"all"* the data the Excel report needs.  You may want to sort by a significant field , but other than that order and formatting are irrelevant at this point.

   [image: The data in an Access Query]
2. Export your data to a **new** Excel file. For some reason, **Excel likes to create the file** itself, if it's going to be used as a template.

   > **It's only one line of code to export from Access to Excel**:
   >
   > ```
   > DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "myQueryname", _
   >                               "c:\yourPath\newFilename.xlsx", True, "myWorksheetName"
   > ```

   ...but it's important enough that *Excel creates the file* that I added a couple checks just to make sure the file doesn't exist and that it was exported properly:

   ```
   Sub ExportToExcel()
       On Error GoTo xferErr
       Const queryName = "qryMyExportQuery1" 'your source query
       Const out_fileName = "c:\myPath\MyDashboard.xlsx" 'this file to created
       Const out_sheetName = "Data" 'worksheet name to create within the file

       If Dir(out_fileName) <> "" Then 
           If MsgBox("Start fresh by deleting: " & vbLf & out_fileName & vbLf & vbLf & _
               "Yes = Delete file; No = export data to existing file.", vbYesNo + _
               vbQuestion, "Delete existing Excel file?") = vbYes Then Kill out_fileName
       End If

       'Export data to Excel:
       DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
           queryName, out_fileName, True, out_sheetName

       If Dir(out_fileName) <> "" Then 'confirm file exists
           MsgBox "File created!"
       Else
           MsgBox "Something went wrong!"
       End If
       Exit Sub
   xferErr:
       Select Case Err
           Case 80: MsgBox "Permission Denied (You might have " & _
                               out_fileName & " open right now."
           Case Else: MsgBox "Error " & Err & vbLf & Err.Description
       End Select
   End Sub
   ```
3. Open the newly created file.  Note the data is on a worksheet named as  specified above.

   [image: imported]

   From now on, *anytime you export that exact same query **to this file*** (or to a **copy** of this file ), the data will clear existing data (only from this tab) and replace the data exactly where it was before.

You can make new worksheets and refer to cells/rows/columns on this sheet, but avoid changing anything.  (Simple stuff like adjusting column width so you can see, is okay.)

When finished setting up the report, you can hide the `Data` tab and forget about it and nobody will even know it's there! (Access doesn't care whether the tab is visible when exporting data.)

---

I threw this (ugly but functional) example together from the sample data in no time.  (It's obviously a lot easier to be picky about formatting etc when you don't have to do it programmatically!)

<sub>All these calculations and objects are calculated based on the other tab.</sub>
[image: finished]

- Any time you re-run the query, everything here will auto-update with no interaction needed.  You can send out or post static copies of this file, as is, with the data tab hidden.

-Or, you could move the `Data' workshet to a separate file and store it in a shared location, will all links from the "dashboard template" point at it.  That way, recipients could just bookmark or save one file, and any time they open the file, it will always display the most current data.

This method is preferable because, among other reasons, you can instantly retract or replace the data any time you with no concern of outdated static copies floating around.

There is so much you can do with am updating report like this.  [Here are other ideas](https://www.google.com/search?q=fancy%20excel%20dashboard&num=100&tbm=isch) for fancy dashboards.

> *Note: **Backup copies*** are always important, but that's more-so when you're learning how to code something to automatically delete or overwrite things.  Any time you make any change you care about to your template, make a copy or two!

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Method** (Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transferspreadsheet-method-access)
- Microsoft Support : [**Export data to Excel**](https://support.office.com/article/export-data-to-excel-64e974e6-ae43-4301-a53e-20463655b1a9)
- Cron : [**How to Generate an MS Access Report to an Excel File**](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/generate-ms-access-report-excel-file-40343.html)

Comment: I already have  a method that does this, what I am unsure about is how to be able to create more than one pivot table that goes on another tab in an Excel file. I have one pivot table that works, but I am unable to get the other 3 to because I am not sure what code I need to add in